# SpringBoot SOAP webservice Dynamic WSDL generation not working If remove Request suffix from RequestPayload element

Tags: web-services, soap, spring-boot, wsdl, spring-ws

I am creating SOAP web service using Spring Boot SOAP Webservice Sample project. If I use following code dynamically generated WSDL shows Operations.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "AvailNotifRequest")
@ResponsePayload
public OTAHotelAvailNotifRS getAvailNotif(@RequestPayload AvailNotifRequest request) {
```

But I need request element to change like this.

```
@PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ")
@ResponsePayload
public OTAHotelAvailNotifRS getOTAHotelAvailNotifRQ(@RequestPayload OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ request) {
```

I found a similar question on this link [Spring web service dynamic wsdl not generating message for a schema element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11485685/spring-web-service-dynamic-wsdl-not-generating-message-for-a-schema-element) answer says we need to add suffix Request after request element like  **AvailNotifRequest** but I want to use **OTAHotelAvailNotifRQ** as my request input.
How can I use this because I am not getting operations in wsdl when I change request input like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [official Spring-WS documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/reference/html/server.html#server-automatic-wsdl-exposure):

> The <dynamic-wsdl> builds a WSDL from a XSD schema by using conventions. It iterates over all element elements found in the schema, and creates a message for all elements. Next, it creates WSDL operation for all messages that end with the defined request or response suffix. The default request suffix is Request; the default response suffix is Response, though these can be changed by setting the requestSuffix and responseSuffix attributes on <dynamic-wsdl />, respectively.

In other words you can use the `setRequestSuffix` and `setResponseSuffix` on [DefaultWsdl11Definition](http://docs.spring.io/spring-ws/site/apidocs/org/springframework/ws/wsdl/wsdl11/DefaultWsdl11Definition.html) in order to specify a request and response suffix different from the default one. In the above case that could for example be:

```
wsdl11Definition.setRequestSuffix("RQ");
wsdl11Definition.setResponseSuffix("RS");
```